# Cplex giving different solutions for equivalent Linear problems

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I'm trying to simplify a linear problem by removing "useless" variables and constraints.
After simplifying my initial problem and solving both instances with **Cplex**, it seems like the results differ but are still really close.

**Initial problem**
objectiveValue ="-606445.47942015168"

I'm also interested in a dual value of some constraint.

dual="-17.47725841435172"

**Simplified Problem**

objectiveValue="-606445.47942014073"

dual="-17.6343"

In order to understand what I was doing wrong, I tried to simplify the original problem step by step.
After some simplification steps which didn't modify the solution, I'm facing this simple constraint :

**QStockeeContrat_(2)(Sc0)(ATS_SereneAtlantique)(07d03d2020)#1
- qStockee_(8)(Sc0)(PITS_SereneAtlantique)(07d03d2020)#7
 = 0**

Then I decide to replace qStockee_(8)(Sc0)(PITS_SereneAtlantique)(07d03d2020)#7 variable by QStockeeContrat_(2)(Sc0)(ATS_SereneAtlantique)(07d03d2020)#1 variable in every constraint and in the objective function.
However the results before and after this change are different as I mentionned before.

Can anyone explain to me why that is happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cplex checks the feasiblity and optimality of the solution in floating point arithmetic. The default tolerance is $1e-6$, which means that a solution can violate the constraints by up to $1e-6$ and the solution is still considered feasible. This also holds for the optimality certificates of the solution.

So probably both solutions are optimal according to the tolerances, and you see a difference because by removing redundant constraints cplex will likely do different simplex iterations and arrive at a different solution.

Further read:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/460195
- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/456197
- https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/tolerances_and_ill_conditi.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed by lowering the feasibility tolerance, the results obtained are even closer and the dual value is the same now.